# Exploratory testing automation in Java/jUnit

Tags: java, testing, selenium, junit, exploratory

I have a large web based system which I have to test.
Are there some tools or some Java based APIs which allow me for automation of exploratory tests. I already have a set of unit tests written in Java using Selenium. Are there some tools, which can generate a ranodm scenarios basing on already written tests. Maybe there are other ways to reach my goal. I found sth which can suit me in Jartege but it uses JML which will produce an extra work in project.

Comment: "Exploratory testing" is non-scripted activity first of all. You can't make it "automated". 

If you're talking about "unit tests written using selenium", than I would assume that there are not "unit" ones, but integration/system.

Comment: I agree with everything you wrote. I am doing research basing on what I have at this moment. Maybe there is some way to simulate exploratory tests using Selenium and JUnit. My first shot is e.g. find a tool which will be able to run a random set of unit test. My second idea is to create a page crawler which will walk through randomly chosen elements of page.

Comment: Make sure you understand the terms you are using as ViktorMalyi said, reference: [Exploratory testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exploratory_testing).  If your understanding of exploratory testing equates to 'random unit testing' then you're missing the point.  What you're trying could be valuable but you need to explain it with words that other people can understand.